# Is there any way in C# to have a parent class use a child's method?

Tags: c#, inheritance

all. I'm trying to get a version of a minimax algorithm to run in c# for a school project. We're trying to make a simple Mancala AI.

To this end, I've set up a tree consisting of nodes that contain all child values and  other information about the board to simulate future moves.

Initially, I was hoping to have the tree have a mutable root - instead of redoing the tree every time the board changed, I was hoping to find the child node that matched the current board, take all the work from then down, expand it, and work from there.

When I go about updating my tree, I'm trying a simple for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
         ...
            if(bCopy.stonesAt(myPits[i]) == (myPits[myPits.Length-i-1]))
                myChildren[i]= new MaxNode(...);
            else
                myChildren[i] = new MinNode(...);
        }
    } else {
        myChildren[i].addChildren(board, depth);
    }
}
```

The ellipses are in place of code or arguments in an attempt to make it readable.

This is what's causing me so much trouble. Since Mancala has certain moves that allow you to go again, there's no way to know if a given child node is a MinNode or a MaxNode. I've set up both MinNodes and MaxNodes as child classes of the abstract class DecisionNode.

I was hoping that the last line (myChildren[i].addChildren(board, depth)) would go down to the lowest level, and use either the MaxNode addChildren or the MinNode addChildren, depending on which was appropriate. However, it uses the DecisionNode addChildren method.

I'd like to keep the code in the seperate classes, as it's messy enough as it is. Is there any way to do so?

Edit: I should mention, I do already have the DecisionNode.addChildren set as virtual and the MinNode & MaxNode addChildren set as override. However, it seems that because the type of myChildren[i] is not known at compile time, it defaults to the parent class instead. The method call goes to

```
public virtual bool addChildren(Board b, int depth) {
        return true;
    }
```

instead of one of the child classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! Or, if not the answer, at least one that will work. Making the DecisionNode method of AddChildren abstract seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The call to myChildren[i].addChildren should result in calling MinNode.addChildren, or MaxNode.addChildren, so long as you marked the method `virtual` in the base class DecisionNode, and `override` in the derived classes.

For example, in your abstract base class, you should have:

```
public abstract class DecisionNode
{
    public virtual void addChildren(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And in your derived classes, you should have:

```
public class MinNode : DecisionNode
{
    public override void addChildren(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Some thing is wrong there. Make addchildren in your base class abstract and see where it starts complaining.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

I had a similar problem recently where I wrote a recursive descendant language parser. The abstract syntax tree is the structure used by the parser to represent the language. I would strongly encourage you to investigate using the Visitor Design Pattern. Basically, you create an IVisitable interface that is implemented by all of your tree nodes. The implementation then implements an Accept method and passes an instance of itself to any IVisitor instance that calls it.

Once you've implemented this pattern you can arbitrarily traverse your tree and do whatever you want without compromising your base code. It is especially helpful when you want some nodes to implement a behavior while others don't. It functions sort of in the opposite of derived classes.

Anyhow, sorry for the backwards answer earlier.

Comment: I'm trying to get to the child class through the parent class, when not knowing which child class it is; not trying to get to the parent through the child.